# mercurial + OSX == fail? hg log abort: Is a directory

Tags: python, macos, mercurial

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ hg init .
$ hg log
abort: Is a directory
$ hg history
abort: Is a directory
```

Darwin Host.local 9.6.1 Darwin Kernel Version 9.6.1: Wed Dec 10 10:38:33 PST 2008; root:xnu-1228.9.75~3/RELEASE_I386 i386

```
$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.2.1)
$ python --version
Python 2.5.4
```

(all installed via macports)

Thoughts? The google gives us nothing.

Update:

(as root):

```
$ hg init /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo; hg log
(works)
```

(as user):

```
$ hg init /tmp/bar
$ cd /tmp/bar; hg log
abort: Is a directory
```

So Travis was right (see comments) it does look like a permission problem somewhere but where? This is a stock install of Leopard barely a week old and stock installs of macport versions of python and mercurial. I hope that isn't mercurial's idea of a good error message when it has a permission problem.

2nd update (from dkbits suggestions below):

```
$ sudo dtruss hg log
[snip]
...
stat("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-   packages/mercurial/templates/gitweb\0", 0xBFFFC7DC, 0x1000)      = 0 0
open_nocancel("/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/mercurial/templates/gitweb\0", 0x0, 0x1B6)        = 3 0
fstat(0x3, 0xBFFFC900, 0x1B6)        = 0 0
close_nocancel(0x3)      = 0 0
write_nocancel(0x2, "abort: Is a directory\n\0", 0x16)       = 22 0
```

Also, the temp directory is where you expected it to be. Permissions look okay on it.

Comment: Why are you trying to look at a log when there have been no commits?

Comment: echo "foo" > test; hg add test; hg commit -m "test commit"; hg log; abort: Is a directory.

Are you dense? The problem is the error message, who cares whether or not you have commits, the problem still exists. And certainly if there are no commits it should report nothing but not an error.

Comment: +1 "The google gives us nothing."

Comment: I went through the same steps without problems. Things that come to mind are permissions and something about the path (perhaps something stupid like spaces?).

Comment: lol why locked?  Schuberts comment here was entirely inappropriate

Comment: Can you try using something like "dtruss hg log" to see what files are being accessed?  Perhaps that will help you can track down the permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another look and it is actually caused by the .hgrc line:

style = gitweb

Why that is I'm not sure but the error message sure sucks still.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I've successfully been using the Mercurial pre-packaged binaries from [here](http://mercurial.berkwood.com/) with the standard Python 2.5.1 install on OSX 10.5 without issue.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ hg init .
$ hg log
$ hg history

$ hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.2.1)

$ python --version
Python 2.5.1
```

Comment: I recall having to use python 2.5.4 due to some issue that was not implemented in python 2.5.4 with regards to HTTPS support I believe. I will look at python 2.6 however. I do suspect that this version problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue233, there is an interesting traceback:

```
hg --traceback qpop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/export/home/bos/lib/python/mercurial/util.py", line 747, in o
    rename(mktempcopy(f), f)
  File "/export/home/bos/lib/python/mercurial/util.py", line 690, in mktempcopy
    fp.write(posixfile(name, "rb").read())
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory
abort: Is a directory
```

Perhaps the permission error is with your temp folder? To find the temp dir, do..

```
$ python
>>> import tempfile
>>> print tempfile.gettempdir()
```

It's should be in `/var/folders/[...]/[...]/-Tmp-/`

Also inspired by the above link, you could try running..

```
$ hg init /tmp/bar
$ cd /tmp/bar
$ hg --traceback log
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

If you symlink your .hgrc somewhere it causes this. Definitely a bug in mercurial (and a stupid error message at that).

```
$ rm -f ~/.hgrc
$ hg init foo
$ cd foo
$ hg log
```

(works)

```
$ ls -l ~/Dropbox/.hgrc
-rw-r--r--@ 1 schubert  staff  83 Jan  9 02:15 /Users/schubert/Dropbox/.hgrc
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/.hgrc ~/.hgrc
$ hg log
abort: Is a directory
$ rm -f ~/.hgrc
$ hg log
```

(works)